# Why does it send the wrong data to our pc if we use both sensors at once?

Tags: c, avr

We have to read out data from 2 sensors. A temperature sensor and a light sensor. We are using an arduino uno with atmel 328P processor. It has to be coded in normal C and not in arduino Sketch. The goal is to send both readings from the sensors through usb to our pc. This is the code:

**main.c:**

```
#include "AVR_TTC_scheduler.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define F_CPU 16E6
#define UBBRVAL 51
#include "CFile1.c"
#include "CFile2.c"
// The array of tasks
sTask SCH_tasks_G[SCH_MAX_TASKS];


/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Dispatch_Tasks()

  This is the 'dispatcher' function.  When a task (function)
  is due to run, SCH_Dispatch_Tasks() will run it.
  This function must be called (repeatedly) from the main loop.

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Dispatch_Tasks(void)
{
   unsigned char Index;

   // Dispatches (runs) the next task (if one is ready)
   for(Index = 0; Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS; Index++)
   {
      if((SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe > 0) && (SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask != 0))
      {
         (*SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask)();  // Run the task
         SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe -= 1;   // Reset / reduce RunMe flag

         // Periodic tasks will automatically run again
         // - if this is a 'one shot' task, remove it from the array
         if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period == 0)
         {
            SCH_Delete_Task(Index);
         }
      }
   }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Add_Task()

  Causes a task (function) to be executed at regular intervals 
  or after a user-defined delay

  pFunction - The name of the function which is to be scheduled.
              NOTE: All scheduled functions must be 'void, void' -
              that is, they must take no parameters, and have 
              a void return type. 

  DELAY     - The interval (TICKS) before the task is first executed

  PERIOD    - If 'PERIOD' is 0, the function is only called once,
              at the time determined by 'DELAY'.  If PERIOD is non-zero,
              then the function is called repeatedly at an interval
              determined by the value of PERIOD (see below for examples
              which should help clarify this).


  RETURN VALUE:  

  Returns the position in the task array at which the task has been 
  added.  If the return value is SCH_MAX_TASKS then the task could 
  not be added to the array (there was insufficient space).  If the
  return value is < SCH_MAX_TASKS, then the task was added 
  successfully.  

  Note: this return value may be required, if a task is
  to be subsequently deleted - see SCH_Delete_Task().

  EXAMPLES:

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,1000,0);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed once after 1000 sch ticks.            

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,0,1000);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed regularly, every 1000 sch ticks.            

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,300,1000);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed regularly, every 1000 ticks.
  Task will be first executed at T = 300 ticks, then 1300, 2300, etc.            

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

unsigned char SCH_Add_Task(void (*pFunction)(), const unsigned int DELAY, const unsigned int PERIOD)
{
   unsigned char Index = 0;

   // First find a gap in the array (if there is one)
   while((SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask != 0) && (Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS))
   {
      Index++;
   }

   // Have we reached the end of the list?   
   if(Index == SCH_MAX_TASKS)
   {
      // Task list is full, return an error code
      return SCH_MAX_TASKS;  
   }

   // If we're here, there is a space in the task array
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask = pFunction;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay =DELAY;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period = PERIOD;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe = 0;

   // return position of task (to allow later deletion)
   return Index;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Delete_Task()

  Removes a task from the scheduler.  Note that this does
  *not* delete the associated function from memory: 
  it simply means that it is no longer called by the scheduler. 

  TASK_INDEX - The task index.  Provided by SCH_Add_Task(). 

  RETURN VALUE:  RETURN_ERROR or RETURN_NORMAL

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

unsigned char SCH_Delete_Task(const unsigned char TASK_INDEX)
{
   // Return_code can be used for error reporting, NOT USED HERE THOUGH!
   unsigned char Return_code = 0;

   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].pTask = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].Delay = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].Period = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].RunMe = 0;

   return Return_code;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Init_T1()

  Scheduler initialisation function.  Prepares scheduler
  data structures and sets up timer interrupts at required rate.
  You must call this function before using the scheduler.  

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Init_T1(void)
{
   unsigned char i;

   for(i = 0; i < SCH_MAX_TASKS; i++)
   {
      SCH_Delete_Task(i);
   }

   // Set up Timer 1
   // Values for 1ms and 10ms ticks are provided for various crystals

   // Hier moet de timer periode worden aangepast ....!
   OCR1A = (uint16_t)625;                // 10ms = (256/16.000.000) * 625
   TCCR1B = (1 << CS12) | (1 << WGM12);  // prescale op 64, top counter = value OCR1A (CTC mode)
   TIMSK1 = 1 << OCIE1A;             // Timer 1 Output Compare A Match Interrupt Enable
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Start()

  Starts the scheduler, by enabling interrupts.

  NOTE: Usually called after all regular tasks are added,
  to keep the tasks synchronised.

  NOTE: ONLY THE SCHEDULER INTERRUPT SHOULD BE ENABLED!!! 

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Start(void)
{
      sei();
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Update

  This is the scheduler ISR.  It is called at a rate 
  determined by the timer settings in SCH_Init_T1().

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
   unsigned char Index;
   for(Index = 0; Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS; Index++)
   {
      // Check if there is a task at this location
      if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask)
      {
         if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay == 0)
         {
            // The task is due to run, Inc. the 'RunMe' flag
            SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe += 1;

            if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period)
            {
               // Schedule periodic tasks to run again
               SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay = SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period;
               SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay -= 1;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            // Not yet ready to run: just decrement the delay
            SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay -= 1;
         }
      }
   }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------


int main()
{
    DDRB = 0xff;
    DDRD = 0xff;
    PORTD = 0xff;
    setup();
    setup2();
    SCH_Init_T1();

    SCH_Add_Task(commando, 0, 1);
    SCH_Add_Task(send_lux, 0, 100);
    SCH_Add_Task(send_temp, 0, 100);

    SCH_Start();

    while (1) {
        SCH_Dispatch_Tasks();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**CFile1.C:**

```
void setup()
{
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = UBBRVAL;
    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);

    ADMUX=(1<<REFS0);// For Aref=AVcc;
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS0);
}


uint16_t read(uint8_t ch) {
    //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
    //ch=ch&0b00000111;
    ADMUX|=ch;

    //Start Single conversion

    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    //Wait for conversion to complete
    while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));

    //Clear ADIF by writing one to it
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

    return(ADC);
}

void transmit(uint8_t lux)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = lux;
}

void send_lux()
{   
    float lux;
    lux = read(0b0000);
    lux = lux/10;
    transmit(lux);


     }

void commando()
{
    if bit_is_set(UCSR0A,RXC0)
    {
        PORTB = UDR0;
    }
}
```

**CFile2.c:**

```
void setup2()
{
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = UBBRVAL;
    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);

    ADMUX=(1<<REFS0);// For Aref=AVcc;
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS0);
}


uint16_t read2(uint8_t ch) {
    //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
    //ch=ch&0b00000111;
    ADMUX|=ch;

    //Start Single conversion

    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    //Wait for conversion to complete
    while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));

    //Clear ADIF by writing one to it
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

    return(ADC);
}

void transmit2(uint8_t temp)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = temp;
}

void send_temp()
{
    float temp;
    temp = read2(0b0001);
    temp = (temp * 5)/1024;
    temp = ((temp -0.5) *100);
    transmit2(temp);

}
```

edit:

```
    #include "AVR_TTC_scheduler.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
//#define F_CPU 16E6
#define UBBRVAL 51
//#include "CFile1.c"
//#include "CFile2.c"
// The array of tasks
sTask SCH_tasks_G[SCH_MAX_TASKS];


/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Dispatch_Tasks()

  This is the 'dispatcher' function.  When a task (function)
  is due to run, SCH_Dispatch_Tasks() will run it.
  This function must be called (repeatedly) from the main loop.

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Dispatch_Tasks(void)
{
   unsigned char Index;

   // Dispatches (runs) the next task (if one is ready)
   for(Index = 0; Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS; Index++)
   {
      if((SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe > 0) && (SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask != 0))
      {
         (*SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask)();  // Run the task
         SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe -= 1;   // Reset / reduce RunMe flag

         // Periodic tasks will automatically run again
         // - if this is a 'one shot' task, remove it from the array
         if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period == 0)
         {
            SCH_Delete_Task(Index);
         }
      }
   }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Add_Task()

  Causes a task (function) to be executed at regular intervals 
  or after a user-defined delay

  pFunction - The name of the function which is to be scheduled.
              NOTE: All scheduled functions must be 'void, void' -
              that is, they must take no parameters, and have 
              a void return type. 

  DELAY     - The interval (TICKS) before the task is first executed

  PERIOD    - If 'PERIOD' is 0, the function is only called once,
              at the time determined by 'DELAY'.  If PERIOD is non-zero,
              then the function is called repeatedly at an interval
              determined by the value of PERIOD (see below for examples
              which should help clarify this).


  RETURN VALUE:  

  Returns the position in the task array at which the task has been 
  added.  If the return value is SCH_MAX_TASKS then the task could 
  not be added to the array (there was insufficient space).  If the
  return value is < SCH_MAX_TASKS, then the task was added 
  successfully.  

  Note: this return value may be required, if a task is
  to be subsequently deleted - see SCH_Delete_Task().

  EXAMPLES:

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,1000,0);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed once after 1000 sch ticks.            

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,0,1000);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed regularly, every 1000 sch ticks.            

  Task_ID = SCH_Add_Task(Do_X,300,1000);
  Causes the function Do_X() to be executed regularly, every 1000 ticks.
  Task will be first executed at T = 300 ticks, then 1300, 2300, etc.            

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

unsigned char SCH_Add_Task(void (*pFunction)(), const unsigned int DELAY, const unsigned int PERIOD)
{
   unsigned char Index = 0;

   // First find a gap in the array (if there is one)
   while((SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask != 0) && (Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS))
   {
      Index++;
   }

   // Have we reached the end of the list?   
   if(Index == SCH_MAX_TASKS)
   {
      // Task list is full, return an error code
      return SCH_MAX_TASKS;  
   }

   // If we're here, there is a space in the task array
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask = pFunction;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay =DELAY;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period = PERIOD;
   SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe = 0;

   // return position of task (to allow later deletion)
   return Index;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Delete_Task()

  Removes a task from the scheduler.  Note that this does
  *not* delete the associated function from memory: 
  it simply means that it is no longer called by the scheduler. 

  TASK_INDEX - The task index.  Provided by SCH_Add_Task(). 

  RETURN VALUE:  RETURN_ERROR or RETURN_NORMAL

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

unsigned char SCH_Delete_Task(const unsigned char TASK_INDEX)
{
   // Return_code can be used for error reporting, NOT USED HERE THOUGH!
   unsigned char Return_code = 0;

   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].pTask = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].Delay = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].Period = 0;
   SCH_tasks_G[TASK_INDEX].RunMe = 0;

   return Return_code;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Init_T1()

  Scheduler initialisation function.  Prepares scheduler
  data structures and sets up timer interrupts at required rate.
  You must call this function before using the scheduler.  

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Init_T1(void)
{
   unsigned char i;

   for(i = 0; i < SCH_MAX_TASKS; i++)
   {
      SCH_Delete_Task(i);
   }

   // Set up Timer 1
   // Values for 1ms and 10ms ticks are provided for various crystals

   // Hier moet de timer periode worden aangepast ....!
   OCR1A = (uint16_t)625;                // 10ms = (256/16.000.000) * 625
   TCCR1B = (1 << CS12) | (1 << WGM12);  // prescale op 64, top counter = value OCR1A (CTC mode)
   TIMSK1 = 1 << OCIE1A;             // Timer 1 Output Compare A Match Interrupt Enable
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Start()

  Starts the scheduler, by enabling interrupts.

  NOTE: Usually called after all regular tasks are added,
  to keep the tasks synchronised.

  NOTE: ONLY THE SCHEDULER INTERRUPT SHOULD BE ENABLED!!! 

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void SCH_Start(void)
{
      sei();
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*-

  SCH_Update

  This is the scheduler ISR.  It is called at a rate 
  determined by the timer settings in SCH_Init_T1().

-*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
   unsigned char Index;
   for(Index = 0; Index < SCH_MAX_TASKS; Index++)
   {
      // Check if there is a task at this location
      if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].pTask)
      {
         if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay == 0)
         {
            // The task is due to run, Inc. the 'RunMe' flag
            SCH_tasks_G[Index].RunMe += 1;

            if(SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period)
            {
               // Schedule periodic tasks to run again
               SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay = SCH_tasks_G[Index].Period;
               SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay -= 1;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            // Not yet ready to run: just decrement the delay
            SCH_tasks_G[Index].Delay -= 1;
         }
      }
   }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup2()
{
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = UBBRVAL;
    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);

    ADMUX=(1<<REFS0);// For Aref=AVcc;
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS0);
}


uint16_t read2(uint8_t ch) {
    //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
    //ch=ch&0b00000111;
    ADMUX|=ch;

    //Start Single conversion

    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    //Wait for conversion to complete
    while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));

    //Clear ADIF by writing one to it
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

    return(ADC);
}

void transmit2(uint8_t send)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = send;
}

void send_temp()
{
    float temp;
    temp = read2(0b0001);
    temp = (temp * 5)/1024;
    temp = ((temp -0.5) *100);
    transmit2(temp);_delay_ms(10);

}


void send_lux()
{
    float lux;
    lux = read2(0b0000);
    lux = lux/10;
    transmit2(lux);_delay_ms(10);

}

void commando()
{
    if bit_is_set(UCSR0A,RXC0)
    {
        PORTB = UDR0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    DDRB = 0xff;
    DDRD = 0xff;
    PORTD = 0xff;
    //setup();
    setup2();
    SCH_Init_T1();

    SCH_Add_Task(commando, 0, 500);
    SCH_Add_Task(send_lux, 0, 1000);
    SCH_Add_Task(send_temp, 500, 1000);

    SCH_Start();

    while (1) {
        SCH_Dispatch_Tasks();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you required to use a scheduler? Seems like you're over complicating things. If you need to send on a specific interval, then you can use a timer.

Comment: Which sensor is sending wrong data? Can you explain what CFile1.c and CFile2.c are? Please give more context.

Comment: @DigitalNinja yes we are required to use the scheduler it was given to us for the project.

Comment: @MarcoRamírez in C1 a light sensor is read and the values are send back to the computer. C2 does the same for temperature. Individually the components work (unplugging and commenting out the files and functions the other sensor uses) but, together the light sensor gets wrong values.

Comment: What happens when you give each task a different `delay`? `SCH_Add_Task(send_lux, 0, 100);
 SCH_Add_Task(send_temp, 0, 300);`

Comment: I would also have just one `read` function (that's what passing in the channel is for). That way you know you're only doing one conversion at a time.

Comment: the source listings for `Cfile1.c` and `Cfile2.c` do not compile.  They are (amongst other problems) missing the necessary `#include` statements for the needed head files

Comment: So I put everything in one file, created an offset in the the delay and now there is the following problem: temperature works fine but lux (which is meant to scale from 0-100 is set to 14 and starts scaling with temperature new code above under addit

Comment: found the problem and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

there is a race condition on the ADC handling. Suggest using a mutex to limit access to the ADC to only one task at a time.